# Vim run command over text object

Tags: vim

I know you can use Visual mode to run a command like `:sort` over a selection. It appears to expand the command to: `:'<,'>sort`.

Is there any way to run an internal or external command over a text-object, like a paragraph? Ideally I would be able to do something like `ip` + `sort` to sort a paragraph of text without manually creating the visual selection. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use text-object selections in Visual mode, eg. `vip:sort`. I guess I didn't think about doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:'{,'}sort
```

Also - since you know about '< and '> try :help '<